# Unable to make http post request in angular js

Tags: java, android, angularjs, http, post

I am trying to build an android app and for its authentication trying to hit http post request from my login.js and the webservices is hosted in another system. But I am receiving this error which I can see while inspecting the device on chrome.

logs.txt

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token J
at Object.parse (native)
at fromJson (file:///android_asset/resources/js/angular/angular.js:1231:14)
at defaultHttpResponseTransform (file:///android_asset/resources/js/angular/angular.js:9248:16)
at file:///android_asset/resources/js/angular/angular.js:9339:12
at forEach (file:///android_asset/resources/js/angular/angular.js:336:20)
```

login.js

```
    $http.post("http://192.xxx.x.x:xxxx/HCPApp/authenticateUserJSONP?j_username=admin_user&j_password=password&userId="+androidUserLoginId+"&password="+password+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").
    success(function(response) {
        var displayName = userName;
        if(response.authenticationStatus==true){
            localStorage.setItem("userId", androidUserLoginId);
            localStorage.setItem("password", password);
            localStorage.setItem("domain", domain);
            localStorage.setItem("userName", userName);
            localStorage.setItem("loggedInStatus",true);
            loggedIn=true;
            var url = "Android.html?name="+userName+"&password="+password+"&domain=TCS";
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        else{
            ons.notification.alert({
                message: 'Username & Password do not match.',
                title:'Login-Error'
            });

        }
    }).
    error(function (data) {
        ons.notification.alert({
            message: 'Please try again later.',
            title:'Network Error'
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally this unexpected token J, Unexpected token U, unexpected token O appears when there is a problem in parsing the data using stringify/parse before storing or retriving it to or from localStorage. Check where have you used JSON.stringify/JSON.parse and the data stored in localstorage.